# How can I check which version of Python is required to run my script?

Tags: python

I wrote a Python program, and I'm using a library that requires Python >= 3.0. When I wrote some code, I used some syntax introduced in 3.2, maybe 3.6, it was a long time ago! So now I have this piece of code, which will surely not run on Python 2.6, or Python 3.0, but I don't know exactly the *minimum* version required to run my script.

So, how can I find out what's the minimum Python version that runs my script?

Comment: http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1986/11/26

Comment: Run it on older and older versions until it breaks?

Comment: @MichaelGeary - Yes, that.

Comment: Maybe if you have an example of the syntax someone might know...

Comment: I would start with 3.0 right away and if it passes that then you know you are good for each of the Python 3 version. Python 2 is a different story. 2 and 3 are not exactly compatible. And 2.6 and below are deprecated so you shouldn't have to worry about those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [tox](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tox) library allows you to test a package using multiple versions of python. That will help you find out which versions your package will run on.

This requires a test script (such as unit tests) that exercise your code sufficiently to surface issues.